# \overset and align environment: how to get correct alignment?

Tags: align

I'm using the `align` environment together with the `\overset` command to put some text over a relation symbol. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=g(x)\\
    &\overset{something}{=} h(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

And the output is

[image: wrong alignment]

As you can see the alignment is wrong, or at least is not what I want! I would like the two equal signs to be aligned one to the other, while with my code I get the alignment of the first equal sign with the start of the text over the symbol!

I've already tried with

```
\overset{something}{&=} h(x)
```

and

```
\overset{something}&{=} h(x)
```

but both solutions led to an error.

How can I get the correct alignment?

Edit: the original question was about `\buildrel`, but, as @egreg said in a comment, this command is not supported in LaTeX, so I've substituted it with `\overset`.

Comment: You should really reconsider writing longer text above a = like that.  IMO it does not belong there in print. It can be fine on a black board. But does not belong in print.

Comment: `\buildrel` is not a supported command in LaTeX. Use `\overset` (that needs `amsmath`, which you use anyway).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`aligned-overset`](https://ctan.org/pkg/aligned-overset) package now provides an easy solution for this: Just write

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f(x)&=g(x)\\
  \overset{something}&{=} h(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Corresponding output]

Answer (score 10):

I would stack something on top of a relation using `\stackrel{<stack>}{<relation>}` (of something similar like `\overset`) and use [`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)'s `\mathclap`. Space corrections can be accommodated using an appropriate `\hspace`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= g(x) \\
       &\buildrel{something}\over{=} h(x)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= g(x) \\
       &\stackrel{\mathclap{\text{something}}}{=} \hspace*{1.5em} h(x) \\
       &\overset{\mathclap{\text{something}}}{=} \hspace*{1.5em} h(x)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

However, avoid lengthy phrases on symbols. Instead you could define a new symbol to represent the relation.

Comment: `\overset`, not `\stackrel`

Comment: @egreg: nice trick! May I ask you why you used `\hspace*` instead of simply `\hspace`?

Comment: May be `&\overset{\text{\llap{somethin}g}}{=} h(x)`?

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be using `\buildrel`, which is not a supported command of LaTeX, but `\overset`.

You can get alignment using a phantom, but in my opinion it's better to add a side condition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Possible way
\begin{align*}
f(x)&\overset{\hphantom{\text{something}}}{=}g(x)\\
    &\overset{\text{something}}{=} h(x)
\end{align*}

Better way
\begin{alignat*}{2}
f(x) &= g(x) \\
     &= h(x) &&\qquad\text{(something)}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that t achieve the "better way" you can also utilise the ```tag```command.

Comment: With tag command, it will be needed the dollar sign to use it with math equations inside the tag command. I'm not sure whether I would like to use tag command. I would like that everything goes to the closest to the right margin possible, like with tag, but with a more practical use, like in the egreg ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution which use the length of the box containing `\buildrel{something}\over{=}` for negative shift

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{$\buildrel{something}\over{=}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=g(x)\\
    &=\kern-0.7\mylength{\buildrel{something}\over{\phantom{=}}} h(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using `\stackon`.  The overset gap is set to 2pt using the optional argument.  The text has been set in `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
f(x)&\stackon{=}{\phantom{\text{\scriptsize something}}}g(x)\\
    &\stackon[2pt]{=}{\text{\scriptsize something}} h(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414223/114322) by @Marcel is the right way to do this, but since that is a new package, and may not be available everywhere, I'm currently using `hspace` to move the *other* relational symbols to be aligned with the o

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  f(x)&\hspace*{10 pt}=g(x)\\
  \overset{something}&{=} h(x)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```