# Overleaf \usepackage{aligned-overset} -> "file 'aligned-overset.sty' not found"

Tags: overleaf, ctan

The code (recomended in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/414223/128042):

```
\usepackage{aligned-overset}
```

gives in Overleaf the error message:

> file 'aligned-overset.sty' not found

But "aligned-overset" is on CTAN https://ctan.org/pkg/aligned-overset?lang=de
and included in TeX Live.

Why does it not work automatically?
How can I do it manually? When I downloaded the .zip from CTAN, there was no .sty inside the folder.

Comment: Which TeXLive? Overleaf used TeXLive 2017! You probably should not be doing that anyway. Adding say Def on a `=` is nice on a blackboard, but poor in something typeset. Write it in words instead.

Comment: BTW: you can run tex (not latex) on the DTX file to get the `.sty`, but again, I would not use this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) As mentioned in the comments, we're still running TeX Live 2017 for new projects. We know that we need to stay more current and we're working on releasing an updated TeX Live distribution for new projects in the coming months.

Since the package in question was added to CTAN in 2018, it's not yet available on Overleaf at the time of writing. Generally, for relatively simple, self-contained packages, you can download the .sty file from CTAN and upload it to your Overleaf project to use it. As long as the package code does not depend on new features of other packages or changes to binaries distributed as part of a newer TeX Live version, it's possible to use updated or new packages on Overleaf this way.

However, since this package was distributed to CTAN as a `.dtx` rather than a `.sty`, the simplest option is to download the `.sty` file from the [TeX Live sources for the package](http://www.tug.org/texlive//devsrc/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/aligned-overset/). This `.sty` file can then be uploaded to your Overleaf project without needing to process the `.dtx` file separately.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile all necessary files (.sty, .tex etc.) in a .ZIP file and upload it to Overleaf as a project file. Instruction is here:

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Uploading_a_project

And @daleif has given the instruction how to extract the style files, and I cite from the readme-file:

> To in­stall, you can run tex align-overset.dtx and copy the gen­er­ated file aligned-overset.sty to a di­rec­tory in the search path of your TeX in­stal­la­tion. For quick eval­u­a­tion, you can also re­name align-overset.dtx to align-overset.sty and use that file di­rectly.

So you can probably rename the .DTX-file and upload it together with other files and it will work.