# How to align part of \stackrel

Tags: alignment

I am trying to align the three = using align. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \geq 1} &= \prod_{j \geq 2}\\
&\stackrel{abc, \, xyz} =  \iint_{S}\\
&= \oint_\gamma .
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

However, I have trouble with the second one since it is part of \stackrel and I cannot put & in front of the second =. What I actually get with the above code is the following.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome! In general I'd advise against using a long piece of material above the equals sign; better to set it to the right of the corresponding formula part as a parenthetical comment.

Comment: This question seems to be very close to [`\overset` and align environment: how to get correct alignment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257529/73317). @QANgô, do the answers there solve your problem?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks egreg and frougon, the answers in the link completely solves my problem.